# MSSQL T-SQL Table Hierachy including parent/child(group)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, foreign-keys

I have a query that successfully lists a databases table hierarchy in relation to level of FK/checks on referenced tables and columns.

This will depict the order in which data is deleted/inserted.

Problem is, within this I want to include that path i.e. 
levels 1 through to 'x' but also the group path each follows (some might have multiple paths through the levels).

Anyone have any suggestions, currently use CTE to recursively grab the level. Possibly use the FK referenced table-name?

```
  ;with    cteTbHierarchy 
      as ( 
           SELECT  distinct
                    1 as LevelID
                  , OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(Parent.object_id) as TableOwner
                  , Parent.name as TableName
                  , Parent.object_id as TbObjID
                  , OBJECT_NAME(RefKey.referenced_object_id) as Referenced_Tablename
                  , RefKey.referenced_object_id
                  , RefKey.referenced_column_id
           from     sys.objects Parent
           left outer join sys.foreign_key_columns RefKey
                    On RefKey.parent_object_id = Parent.object_id
                       and RefKey.parent_object_id <> RefKey.referenced_object_id
                       and RefKey.constraint_column_id = 1
           where    RefKey.parent_object_id is null
                    and Parent.type = 'U'
                    and Parent.name <> 'dtproperties'
           UNION ALL
           /* add tables that reference the anchor rows */
           SELECT   H.LevelID + 1
                  , OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(Parent.object_id) as TableOwner
                  , OBJECT_NAME(Parent.object_id) as TableName
                  , Parent.object_id as TbObjID
                  , OBJECT_NAME(RefKey.referenced_object_id) as Referenced_Tablename
                  , RefKey.referenced_object_id
                  , RefKey.referenced_column_id
           from     sys.objects Parent
           inner join sys.foreign_key_columns RefKey
                    On RefKey.parent_object_id = Parent.object_id
                       and RefKey.parent_object_id <> RefKey.referenced_object_id
                       and RefKey.constraint_column_id = 1
           inner join cteTbHierarchy H
                    on H.TbObjID = RefKey.referenced_object_id 

           where    Parent.type = 'U'
                    and Parent.name <> 'dtproperties'
         )
select  distinct a.LevelID,
        a.TableOwner,
        a.TableName,
        a.Referenced_Tablename,
        cols.name as Referenced_ColName,
        REPLACE(a.tablename,(LEFT(SUBSTRING(a.TableName, charindex('.',a.TableName), 50),50)),'') as TableArea,
        REPLACE(a.Referenced_Tablename,(LEFT(SUBSTRING(a.Referenced_Tablename, charindex('.',a.Referenced_Tablename), 50),50)),'') as RefTableArea
from    cteTbHierarchy a
left join sys.columns cols
                    on a.referenced_object_id = cols.object_id
                    AND a.referenced_column_id = cols.column_id
order by LevelID asc 
      , TableName;
```

Comment: What do you plan to do if you encounter cycles?

Comment: If the table references itself and would cause a continuous loop then break after 1-2 max resursions where tablename = talbename?

Comment: or possibly just exclude them from this dataset :P

Comment: I can easily recall having seen cycles between 4-5 tables, and there are probably larger examples out there.

Comment: Any further help in figuring out how to do this?